# the domain alias in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with domain alias wordpress.

I have two site I call is site A and site B.

- **server A have IpA and domainA.net**
- **server B have IpB and domainA.net/siteB**

and site B is t**he wordpress.** 
when I click domain **domainA.net** it will call **siteA at server A**. when I click domain **domainA.net/siteB** it will call siteB at server B.

I config redirect to call 2 site to be ok. but when I call site wp-admin (**domainA.net/siteB/wp-admin**) then It ok, but some link redirect to IpB
submit form then redirect to **domainA.net/wp-admin is wrong**.

so how to set domain alias is right?
config in wordpress for siteUrl domainA.net/siteB and home domainA.net/siteB
htaccess in wordpress

```
RewriteBase /siteB/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /siteB/index.php [L]
```

And  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] return is IpB. I want to return is domain domainA.net/siteB